# Convert Sql Pivot table query to linq in EF4

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have been doing one task from last three days. I try to convert one sql query into linq which is based on "Convert Columns into Rows" called Pivot table.

**My SQL Query is as under.**

```
SELECT project_name
,SUNDAY
,MONDAY
,TUESDAY
,WEDNESDAY
,THRUSDAY
,FRIDAY
,SATURDAY
FROM
(
    SELECT project_name
    ,personnel_name
    ,DATENAME(dw, report_date) AS day_name
    ,SUM(hours) AS HOURS
    FROM [TimeSheet]

    INNER JOIN [ProjectMaster] 
    ON [TimeSheet].[project_id] = [ProjectMaster].[project_id]

    INNER JOIN [Personnel] 
    ON [TimeSheet].[personnel_id] = [Personnel].[personnel_id]
    WHERE report_date BETWEEN getdate() - 7 AND getdate()
    GROUP BY project_name, personnel_name, DATENAME(dw, report_date)
) sourceQuery PIVOT (SUM(hours) 
 FOR day_name IN 
 (SUNDAY,MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY,THRUSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY)) AS pvt
```

**What I do so far convert it into linq is below!!!**

```
var before = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
DateTime firstSunday = new DateTime(1753, 1, 7); 

var DayWiseTS = from TSList in objWPFEntities.Timesheets.Include("ProjectMaster").Include("Personnel")
where (TSList.report_date >= before && TSList.report_date <= System.DateTime.Now)
select new { TSList.ProjectMaster.project_name, TSList.Personnel.personnel_name, TSList.report_date, TSList.hours } into sourceQuery
group sourceQuery by new { sourceQuery.project_name, sourceQuery.personnel_name, sourceQuery.report_date, sourceQuery.hours } into pvt
select new 
{ 
projectname = pvt.Key.project_name,
Sunday = (EntityFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, pvt.Key.report_date.Value) % 7 == 0 ? pvt.Sum(g => g.hours) : 0),
Monday = (EntityFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, pvt.Key.report_date.Value) % 7 == 1 ? pvt.Sum(g => g.hours) : 0),
Tuesday = (EntityFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, pvt.Key.report_date.Value) % 7 == 2 ? pvt.Sum(g => g.hours) : 0),
Wednesday = (EntityFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, pvt.Key.report_date.Value) % 7 == 3 ? pvt.Sum(g => g.hours) : 0),
Thrusday = (EntityFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, pvt.Key.report_date.Value) % 7 == 4 ? pvt.Sum(g => g.hours) : 0),
Friday = (EntityFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, pvt.Key.report_date.Value) % 7 == 5 ? pvt.Sum(g => g.hours) : 0),
Saturday = (EntityFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, pvt.Key.report_date.Value) % 7 == 6 ? pvt.Sum(g => g.hours) : 0)
};
```

I got result in both query but in sql, I got perfect result as I required, but in linq, I haven't get required data as sql.

**sql result ::**

[image]

**Linq result ::**

[image]

I think, in my linq query, I failed to do group by on hours!!

can any one help me on this??

Answer (score 1):

Give up. EF doesn't have tool set to run pivot queries and even if you somehow manage to do it, the performance of the query will be terrible. Instead of trying to convert the SQL query to Linq query simply create class which have properties with same names as result set of your query:

```
public class HoursPerDay {
    // if you want different names you must use aliases in your query too
    public string project_name { get; set; } 
    public int SUNDAY { get; set; }
    public int MONDAY { get; set; }
    public int TUESDAY { get; set; }
    public int WEDNESDAY { get; set; }
    public int THURSDAY { get; set; }
    public int FRIDAY { get; set; }
    public int SATURDAY { get; set; }
}
```

and use `objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery` or `dbContext.Database.SqlQuery`:

```
var data = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<HoursPerDay>(yourSqlQuery);
```

To make simple conclusion: Linq-to-entities does not ultimately replace SQL. SQL is still complementary tool when working with Entity Framework.

Comment: I've achieved 98% of my work, just not getting result as I have shown into sql, when you compare my both of output which I have shown in image, you get to know that only grouping having some problem in linq query. which I need to resolve!! that's why I need professionals help to complete it, So It's completely new thing!!! pivoting is done into that query already!!

Answer (score 0):

As Ladislav (and my own experience) say: pivoting in a sproc is far more efficient than doing it client side. But you may have reasons not to do that. Anyway, I think I know what the problem is. You should not include the hours in the grouping:

```
group sourceQuery by new { sourceQuery.project_name, sourceQuery.personnel_name,
                           sourceQuery.report_date } into pvt
```

The statements in the result set stay the same:

```
...
Sunday = (EntityFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, pvt.Key.report_date.Value) % 7
         == 0 ? pvt.Sum(g => g.hours) : 0),
```